Error executing query: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Datatable')
An error occurred when I try to submit the form using jquey in Laravel. below is my code and i messed up for more than 3 hours.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Data Visualization</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Database Information</h1>
    <p>DB Port: {{ env('DB_PORT') }}</p>
    <p>DB Name: {{ env('DB_DATABASE') }}</p>
    <p>Username: {{ env('DB_USERNAME') }}</p>
    <p>Password: {{ env('DB_PASSWORD') }}</p>

    <h2>Query Box</h2>
    <!-- Display query input box -->
    <textarea id="query-box" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your SQL query"></textarea>
    <button onclick="executeQuery()">Execute Query</button>

    <h2>Visualization</h2>
    <div id="chart-container">
    </div>



     <script>
        // Function to execute the query
        function executeQuery() {
    const query = document.getElementById('query-box').value;

    fetch('execute-query', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    })
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
        const chartData = new google.visualization.Datatable();
        chartData.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        chartData.addColumn('integer', 'Value Count');
        data.forEach(item => {
            chartData.addRow([item.name, item.value_count]);
        });

        const options = {
            title: 'Query Result Visualization',
            width: 600,
            height: 400
        };

        const chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
        chart.draw(chartData, options);
    })
   .catch(error => console.error('Error executing query:', error));
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>


I'm coding a small project like someone will write a query on runtime and graph visualization occur. I just want, based on the query a graph visualization occur.
my Controller code is shown below:
 public function executequery(Request $request)
{

    $query = $request->input('query');
    // Process the query and return the response
    // For example, you can use the DB facade to execute the query
    $result = DB::select($query);$data = [];
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $data[] = [
            'name' => $row->name,
            'value_count' => $row->value_count
        ];
    }

    return response()->json($data);
}


Did you ask the Google charts to load that?

yeah.  I'm asking it to do so in  executeQuery function.

i'm not seeing this https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs
